# Bijection on the integers below x

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

i'm working on image processing, and i'm writing a parallel algorithm that iterates over all the pixels in an image, and changes the surrounding pixels based on it's value. In this algorithm, minor non-deterministic is acceptable, but i'd rather minimize it by only querying distant pixels simultaneously. Could someone give me an algorithm that bijectively maps the integers below n to the integers below n, in a fast and simple manner, such that two integers that are close to each other before mapping are likely to be far apart after application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the pixels to be a one dimentional array you could use a hash function j = i*p % n where n is the zero based index of the last pixel and p is a prime number chosen to place the pixel far enough away at each step.  % is the remainder operator in C, mathematically I'd write j(i) = i p (mod n).

So if you want to jump at least 10 rows at each iteration, choose p > 10 * w where w is the screen width.  You'll want to have a lookup table for p as a function of n and w of course.

Note that j hits every pixel as i goes from 0 to n.

CORRECTION: Use (mod (n + 1)), not (mod n).  The last index is n, which cannot be reached using mod n since n (mod n) == 0.

Comment: Aaah, you had similar idea.. but my answer took longer time :-) But I'm not sure you can do it this way. I think the `n` must be prime here, not `p`.

Comment: I considered this, but i'd rather avoid checking that p is coprime with n. (Which is required for this algo to work)

Comment: I should add that p does have to be prime, but it does have to be *mutually* prime with n, that is n and p should have no common factors.  It's easiest  just to choose a prime that works for all screen sizes.

Comment: I suppose i know my image isn't going to be more than 10,000 pixels wide, i could just choose a very large prime. I'll do that.

Comment: @DanielOfTaebl: no, you just need to choose one prime that works for the minimum size or use a lookup table.

Comment: @TomasT. No, mod n puts the result back on the screen

Comment: @DanielOfTaebl Be careful, if p is nearly k*n then you'll end up with close points anyway!  Best to have p around n/2 for which you can just use a lookup table.

Comment: Also i don't think it should be mod n + 1. If we're assuming zero-based indexing, mod n is the way to go.

Comment: @DanielOfTaebl: I was using n as the highest index, not number of items, but no matter, you've got it clear

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity let's say `n` is a power of two. Could you simply reverse the order of the least significant `log2(n)` bits of the number?

Comment: I had exactly the same idea - just revert the bits.

Comment: Yeah, but we can't assume n is a power of two. Is there some subtraction or something that i can do afterward

Comment: @Daniel, I think that assuption is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from reverting the bit order, you can use **modulo**. Say N is a prime number (like 521), so for all x = 0..520 you define a function:

f(x) = x * fac mod N

which is bijection on 0..520. `fac` is arbitrary number different from 0 and 1. For example for N = 521 and fac = 122 you get the following mapping:

[image]

which as you can see is quite uniform and not many numbers are near the diagonal - there are some, but it is a small proportion.